# Get sharepointids when creating a DriveItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

So I am creating a **DriveItem** (Both files and folder) and on a successful creation the newly created **DriveItem** will be returned with the response.

My issue is that I need the "sharepointids", currently I need to make a get request to retrieve this information. Is there a way to include the "sharepointids" in the **DriveItem** object sent back on a successful creation?

Answer (score 0):

So I did some digging into this and I also could not retrieve the sharepointId from the response after creating a drive item while using both delegated and application permissions. I then had a look at the [sharepointID documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepointids?view=graph-rest-1.0) and it says that the sharepointID property is not returned from OneDrive personal. Check if you are creating the driveitem on a OneDrive personal account.

Comment: Hi Fiona, no I am currently working with One Drive business and SharePoint sites. So I shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. Let me look more into this and try and figure out why you may be facing this issue

Comment: So try making your api call with a $select query parameter for the sharepointId and let me know how it goes

Comment: I have already tried the $select, and unfortunately it didn't do anything

Comment: I have seen a similar issue on Git: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6805. Please try asking this there, they will most likely resolve the issue from there

Comment: It is quite similar but not the same, my issue is when creating an item. Normal get of drive items works perfectly for me. I have asked nonetheless, thank you :)